# Problema ao inserir dados em uma tabela que contém chaves estrangeiras

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-select, sql-insert, chave-estrangeira

**Olá, pessoal!**

Bem... O meu problema é o seguinte:
Tenho um banco de dados MySQL que possui 3 tabelas (Cliente, Evento, Equipamento). A tabela evento possui duas chaves estrangeiras, a primeira delas referenciando o id da tabela Cliente (id_cliente) e a segunda referenciando o id da tabela Equipamento. Ao inserir valores nas tabelas Cliente e Equipamento tudo ok, mas, ao inserir valores na tabela Evento, referenciando um id específico das outras tabelas, os valores inseridos referenciam também os outros id's registrados.

**Para ser mais claro:**

**Um exemplo**: Vou registrar um evento contratado pelo cliente de id 1, ponho todos os dados em seus respectivos lugares, inclusive o número do id igual a 1 onde tem que ficar o valor da chave estrangeira. O código é executado, porém, quando executo um "Select" para checar, os dados inseridos estão referenciando também o cliente de id 2.

**"Select" exibindo os valores inseridos na tabela Evento:**
[image: Printscreen 1]

**Este "Select" mostra o problema. O valor "Santo Antônio" na coluna "cidade" deveria pertencer somente ao cliente de id 1.**
[image: Printscreen 2]

**PS:** Me desculpem por qualquer erro, sou novo por aqui, inclusive nunca participei de sites de perguntas e respostas. Enfim... Podem me ajudar? O que devo fazer? Porque estou enfrentando este

Comment: O problema é que ao fazer um `SELECT` vem o resultado de todos os `Cliente` ? Desculpe, mas não entendi o seu problema.

Comment: Não, @ThiagoMagalhães. Vou usar o exemplo que usei na publicação. O problema é o seguinte: Suponhamos que eu tenha registrado um evento contratado por um cliente de id 1. Os dados inseridos (utilizando o INSERT INTO), ao invés de referenciar apenas o cliente de id 1 (que foi passado como valor da chave primária no INSERT INTO) referenciam também o cliente de id 2. Ou seja, todas as informações do evento contratado pelo cliente de id 1, ficam registrados como se fossem também do cliente de id 2. Entendeu?

Comment: entendi. pode posta a estrutura das tabelas?

Comment: Sim, @ThiagoMagalhães. Vou postar uma por vez por conta do limite de caracteres.

Comment: create table cliente(
id_cliente int auto_increment not null,
nome varchar(35),
numero varchar(15),
primary key(id_cliente)
);

Comment: create table equipamento(
id_equipamento int auto_increment not null,
nome varchar(8),
primary key(id_equipamento)
);

Comment: create table evento(
id_evento int auto_increment not null,
endereco varchar(40),
dia varchar(8),
horario varchar(5),
fk_cliente int not null,
fk_equipamento int not null,
primary key(id_evento),
constraint foreign key (fk_cliente) references cliente (id_cliente),
constraint foreign key (fk_equipamento) references equipamento (id_equipamento)
);

Comment: Está fazendo o select dessa forma: `SELECT * FROM evento e WHERE e.fk_cliente = 1` ?

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães, dá uma olhada nos prints que coloquei agora na postagem, talvez te ajude a entender o problema.

Comment: Teste: `SELECT * FROM evento e
INNER JOIN cliente c ON (e.fk_cliente = c.id_cliente)`. Se a cidade repetir, é pq mais de um evento na mesma cidade foram registrados para clientes diferentes.

Comment: OBS: Alterei o nome da coluna "endereco", que estava na estrutura da tabela "evento" mostrada acima, para "cidade".

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães, as informações foram exibidas certinho agora. Mas me explica uma coisa, se possível: porque esse problema estava ocorrendo?

Comment: Como era a consulta que você estava fazendo?

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães, desculpa a demora pra responder. Eu tava fazendo a consulta da seguinte maneira: SELECT id_evento,nome,numero,cidade,dia,horario FROM evento,cliente WHERE id_evento = 1; Era mais ou menos assim, não me lembro bem.

Comment: Aliás... Muito obrigado pela ajuda! A maneira que me indicou resolveu o problema. Muito obrigado mesmo, @ThiagoMagalhães!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que você fez:

```
SELECT id_evento,nome,numero,cidade,dia,horario FROM evento,cliente WHERE id_evento = 1;
```

Ele irá concatenar a tupla da tabela `evento` com `id_evento = 1` com cada uma das tuplas da tabela `cliente`.

---

Fazendo desta forma (utilizando `INNER JOIN`):

```
SELECT * FROM evento e INNER JOIN cliente c ON (e.fk_cliente = c.id_cliente)
```

Você só irá concatenar as tuplas da tabela `evento` com os dados da tabela `cliente` de acordo com a condição informada no comando `ON`, que no caso é quando a chave estrangeira de `evento` (`fk_cliente`) for igual ao `id_cliente` presente da tabela do `cliente`.

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu queria saber, @ThiagoMagalhães! Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento e pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Duas coisas que você precisa definir antes de escrever o banco é a normalização. 
Se o cliente pode contratar apenas para a cidade dele ou para outra. No caso de ser para outra, sua tabela evento deve apontar para uma tabela de cidades (IBGE).

O banco para o que você explicou ficaria :

```
create table Cliente(id integer, nome varchar(100), cidade varchar(100));
insert into Cliente(id, nome, cidade) values(1, "jose" , "sao jose");
insert into Cliente(id, nome, cidade) values(2, "maria" , "sao paulo");



create table Equipamento(id integer, descricao varchar(100));
insert into Equipamento(id, descricao) values(1, "telao");

create table Evento(id integer, clienteId integer, equipamentoId integer, dia date);
insert into Evento(id, clienteId,equipamentoId) values(1, 1,1);


select e.id,c.nome,c.cidade,q.descricao 
from Evento e 
join Cliente c ON e.clienteId = c.id 
join Equipamento q ON equipamentoId = q.id;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica, @IsraelZebulon! Ajudou bastante também!